# Double value becoming zero when posted using fromForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I am facing a weird behavior with my .NET application double value is becoming zero on the controller. I have posted `FormData` which contains double values e.g., 58.79711.

While my server language is English this works with both double formats
e.g., 58,79711 and 58.79711. When my server language is Swedish it does not understand double values with a decimal place like 58.79711. while it understands 58,79711.

I don't want to change my server language to English, and I want double values like 58.79711 should not become zero.

Comment: Ideally, you would get the caller to also send the CultureInfo to the controller. This is the only way to ensure the number is always parsed correctly. However, if you can't do that and you have a limited number of cultures that could be used, you can try a series of `Decimal.TryParse()` calls with the different cultures until one is successful. This might be "good enough".

Comment: You can set the current thread's `CurrentUICulture` to `Invariant`, which I believe should fix the issue, but it's been a few years. You should read [the documentation on `CultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0) for the version of .NET you are using (linked to .NET 6 since that's what came up by default).

Comment: @HereticMonkey my application picks culture of server. e.g., swedish. is their any header i can pass in my request whcih make .net application understand to parse double correctly.

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet for the perticular issue? So that it can be easily investigated.